# spring application does not start: SAXParseException: Document root element "beans", must match DOCTYPE root "null"

Tags: java, spring

I just deployed an application to tomcat version 6.0.32 and I get this error from spring. I don't think the xml is invalid

> PAS: 2011-12-28 14:19:08,585 INFO [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader] - 
>   PAS: 2011-12-28 14:19:08,592 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] - 
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 15 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/applicationContext.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Document root element "beans", must match DOCTYPE root "null".
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Document root element "beans", must match DOCTYPE root "null".
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:195)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:131)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:384)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:318)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.rootElementSpecified(XMLDTDValidator.java:1621)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleStartElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:1900)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:764)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1363)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$ContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1318)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3104)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:922)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:235)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:284)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:222)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:173)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:148)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:129)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:145)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:126)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:89)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:262)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.support.AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractRefreshableWebApplicationContext.java:139)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:252)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:190)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:49)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4205)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4704)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:943)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:778)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:504)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1315)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1061)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)

XMl is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"   xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"

  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.5.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-2.5.xsd">

<context:property-placeholder  location="WEB-INF/passport.properties, WEB-INF/config/server.properties"/>
<util:properties id="props" location="WEB-INF/passport.properties" />

<context:component-scan base-package="util" />

<bean id="passportConfig" class="util.PassportBaseConfig"
    p:configLocation="WEB-INF/" autowire="no" factory-method="getInstance"
    init-method="init" p:userDAO-ref="passportUserDao" p:teamDAO-ref="passportTeamDao" 
    p:serverId="${serverId}">
    <constructor-arg ref="props" />

</bean>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From this message

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Document root element "beans", must match DOCTYPE root "null".
```

it seems to me like your DTD is incorrect and there is some version mismatch. You are using a new version in the DTD and supplying older jars.

Comment: just updated the XML. I had copied the bean definitions from the wrong applicationContext.xml. I see that they I'm using xsd definitions .

Comment: Looks like I had an old spring.jar in a separate directory which was messing my build process. Thanks

Comment: Glad it worked out for you. Please accept any answer that helped.

Comment: Try to put .jar in new folder. We found out that our folder (where the .jar was located) contained application.xml file which was totally different than that on the application itself.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a DOC type in your spring config file.

Instead start your spring config file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">
```

Also, be sure to close the beans tag at the end of the config file.

```
</beans>
```

Here is a link to the [IOC Container Info](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html) in the spring 3.1 reference

Comment: well the XML is a well formed XML. The reason I left out beans is because there are lot of other enteries and because of security reasons, I left out some enteries.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this example: [Creating a Spring Application](http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/intro-to-ioc-creating-a-spring-application.html)

Notice the difference between your XML and a proper applicationContext.xml. You're missing all references to the namespace.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this error:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Line
>   ... in XML document from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]
>   is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;
>   lineNumber: ...; columnNumber: ...; Document root element "beans",
>   must match DOCTYPE root "null". org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;
>   Document root element "beans", must match DOCTYPE root "null".

I have resolved it by adding:

```
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
```

in applicationContext.xml file & adding correct version of dependencies, like in my case i have used 3.2.3.RELEASE for spring-context-support dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    <version>**3.2.3.RELEASE**</version>
</dependency>
```