# Spring boot configuration issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm new to springboot and I need to deploy the project using springboot. But when I run the application, the following error message is displayed:

```
2018-12-12 14:22:17,714 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load property source from location 'classpath:/application.xml'
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.loadIntoGroup(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:476)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:465)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:386)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.addPropertySources(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:225)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:195)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:182)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:168)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:74)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:325)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:296)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
    at com.pacer.track.server.bootstrap.Main.main(Main.java:9)
Caused by: java.util.InvalidPropertiesFormatException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 10; columnNumber: 77; Document root element "beans", must match DOCTYPE root "null".
```

I suppose there is something wrong with beans of the application.xml and also looked into related issues saying that there might be different versions of spring in the same project, but I found nothing wrong in the application.xml and the dependencies I brought in. I'd be grateful if someone could help me out with this.

application.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:dubbo="http://dubbo.apache.org/schema/dubbo" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:rabbit="http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://dubbo.apache.org/schema/dubbo http://dubbo.apache.org/schema/dubbo/dubbo.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit/spring-rabbit-1.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.pacer.track.server"/>
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>

    <dubbo:application name="track-server"/>
    <dubbo:registry address="N/A" check="false"/>
    <dubbo:protocol name="rest" port="${http.port}"/>

    <!-- redis config -->
    <import resource="redis-config.xml"/>

    <!-- rabbitmq config -->
    <import resource="rabbit-config.xml"/>

    <!-- database config -->
    <bean id="trackDataSource" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:postgresql://${postgres.host}:${postgres.port}/${postgres.dbname}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${postgres.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${postgres.password}"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="trackSqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="trackDataSource"/>
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:mybatis-config.xml"/>
        <property name="mapperLocations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:mapper/*.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="trackMapperConfigure" class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
        <property name="basePackage" value="com.pacer.track.server.dao.mapper"/>
        <property name="sqlSessionFactoryBeanName" value="trackSqlSessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- properties -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
        <property name="locations">
            <array>
                <value>classpath:api.properties</value>
                <value>classpath:application.properties</value>
            </array>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

[image: spring dependency]

Comment: have a look at:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29695673/document-root-element-beans-must-match-doctype-root-null and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8660308/error-starting-a-spring-application

Comment: Where are your Postgres properties defined?

Comment: @dkb I already seen this one, but I don't have a tomcat dependency and there seems no duplicate dependencies with different versions.

Comment: Do check is you are using DTD of newer version and have older jars or vice versa

Comment: For more reference: https://github.com/dineshbhagat/spring-boot-web-jpa

Comment: @racraman several .properties files

Comment: @dkb thanks, I'll try to look into that.

Comment: Rename your `application.xml` to something else. Spring Boot will load `application.properties`, `application.xml` or `application.yml` and assumes it contains a valid way of expression properties. A `java.util.Properties` object can also be expressed in XML instead of properties and as this is the default resource loading behavior of properties trying to load from a resource `application` will also attempt to load `application.xml`. Also if you are using Spring Boot why the XML?